# I can´t install Cinammon on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, apt, ppa, cinnamon

I'm new on linux and I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 lts. I want to install cinnamon but after typing

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinammon-stable
```

it shows me this:

> `Cannot access PPA (https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~gwendal-lebihan-dev/+archive/cinammon-stable) to get PPA information, please check your internet connection.`

I dont know what to do, and I really want to install cinnamon. 
I hope anybody can help me with this.

Thanks!!

Comment: r u connected with internet ?

Comment: It appears he deleted the stable repo, but still has a nightly build repo.  Just browse the user on launchpad https://launchpad.net/~gwendal-lebihan-dev

Answer (score 2):

That PPA is no longer maintained. Instead, the nightly PPA (ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-nightly) is maintained, but you won't be able to use it on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

You can get Cinnamon from an alternative PPA. Use the following steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tsvetko.tsvetkov/cinnamon
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

These steps are from this [WebUpd8 article](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/06/new-cinnamon-stable-ubuntu-ppas-ubuntu.html).